# Django Admin - Preventing staff from accessing admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm fairly new to Django.

How do I prevent staff users from logging into the Django admin panel? I still want them to be identified as staff, but do not want them to be able to log into the admin panel.
I am using the default Django admin panel.

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of the `is_staff` flag is to give access to the admin panel, what are you using it for and how would you give access instead?

Comment: I'm making a website as my A level project. I'm using it to prevent students from being able to access pages meant for teachers. I know this may not be the intended use but I'm in a pinch. The deadline is Friday this week    ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You're using the `is_staff` flag to mark someone as a teacher but you don't want teachers to be able to log in to the admin?

Comment: Yes, the admin panel is to be for the IT department only, I have added all relevant data management features meant for the teachers on specific web pages. Teachers are default Django users, as are students. Edit: The IT department is superuser

Comment: Using `is_staff` correctly would be ideal but I get that you are under time pressure, would you be fine with limiting admin access to superusers?

Comment: yes, that would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can limit admin access to only superusers by [overriding the default admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) and overriding the [`has_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.has_permission) method in your custom admin site to only return `True` for superusers

myproject/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def has_permission(request):
        return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_superuser
```

myproject/apps.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig


class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):

    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

myproject/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. However, as I was snooping around, I found that even though staff can login, it says that they don't have the permission to do anything which might as well be what I wanted. I'll leave this up for anyone who would find it useful.